# Can I add an object to a struct in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, class, object, data-structures, shared

I have a data struct for a piece of lumber.  I've built a class to handle dimensions (architectural, metric, etc... ) that I'd like to make the data type of the length member of this struct.  VB says I can't use 'new' in my definition unless I make the member 'Shared'.  If I make the member 'Shared' I can't see the data when I try to access the member in my code.

```
 Public Structure PieceInfo
    Dim ProjectNumber As String
    Dim ProjectName As String
    Dim BuildingType As String
    Dim BuildingNumber As String
    Dim BLevel As String
    Dim Batch As String
    Dim Trussname As String
    Dim Span As Single
    Dim PieceName As String
    Dim LumberType As String
    Shared PieceLength As New clsDimension
    Shared StockLength As New clsDimension
    Dim LeftSplicePlate As String
    Dim RightSplicePlate As String
End Structure
```

How can I use my "clsDimension" object as the data type for the "Length" members of my struct?

Comment: That should be a class, not a struct.

Comment: Why not leave PieceLength and StockLength uninitialized in the definition? You can then create a constructor where you can assign them instances of clsDimension.

Comment: I'm fairly new to OO programming.. Why should that be a class and not a struct? Because I want to use an object for a datatype?

Comment: Like @SLaks says, that should be a class. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) for information regarding when to choose a structure or class.  Basically, a structure should be something that represents a single value and is immutable.

Comment: I've always thought a object should contain data and methods changing that data. I guess you can say the 'clsDimension' can change the data for it's member, so that means the whole thing should be a class.  I'm actually using mrtig's suggestion in the code, but will use a class the next time I encounter this. Thanks.

Comment: In c++, structs are typically used for data structures and classes  for business logic, but in .NET they are much different.  In c++, structs and classes are essentially the same--they differ only in the default protection-level of their members--either could be created on the stack or on the heap.  In .NET, a structure is always a value type (on the stack) and a class is always a reference type (on the heap), so that changes your decision making considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the comments indicate: You should change your Struct to a class because you want to reference it. And due to Structs being value types and Classes being reference types, This is what you want:

```
Public Class PieceInfo
    Dim ProjectNumber As String
    Dim ProjectName As String
    Dim BuildingType As String
    Dim BuildingNumber As String
    Dim BLevel As String
    Dim Batch As String
    Dim Trussname As String
    Dim Span As Single
    Dim PieceName As String
    Dim LumberType As String
    Shared PieceLength As New clsDimension
    Shared StockLength As New clsDimension
    Dim LeftSplicePlate As String
    Dim RightSplicePlate As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET Structure don't have default constructor, you'll have to create your own (or a function to initialize the values). But that kind of defeat the purpose of the struct.

```
Public Structure PieceInfo
    Dim ProjectNumber As String
    Dim ProjectName As String
    Dim BuildingType As String
    Dim BuildingNumber As String
    Dim BLevel As String
    Dim Batch As String
    Dim Trussname As String
    Dim Span As Single
    Dim PieceName As String
    Dim LumberType As String
    Dim PieceLength As clsDimension
    Dim StockLength As clsDimension
    Dim LeftSplicePlate As String
    Dim RightSplicePlate As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal t As String)
        PieceLength = New clsDimension
        StockLength = New clsDimension
    End Sub
End Structure
```

But like others said, changing it to a class is the right thing to do. Class is reference type and structure is value type.